# Entity Framework Inverse Property Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three relevant EF models/tables - Transfers, Users, and People. Transfers used to have two properties - TransferredToId (FK - People) and TransferredFromId (FK-People). I changed both of these to point to the Users table instead. However, EF is not seeing the change (Add-Migration creates an empty migration / Update-Database doesn't see db changes - I verified that it sees other changes / works fine overall). Without further ado:

```
public class User {
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("TransferredFrom")]
    public ICollection<Transfer> TransferredFroms { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("TransferredTo")]
    public ICollection<Transfer> TransferredTos { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Transfer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long TransferredFromId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TransferredFromId")]
    public User TransferredFrom { get; set; }

    public long TransferredToId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TransferredToId")]
    public User TransferredTo { get; set; }
}
```

I am following [this example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) - it worked fine with the people table, but now that I deleted all references to Transfer from People, added them to Users, and changed the user properties (to what you see above), EF doesn't seem to see it. No migration, if I manually check db, it shows incorrect FK to People (naturally, given lack of migration). Please let me know if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: public User() {...} this looks like a constructor, I don't think it is meant that way (as a Method).

Comment: That was a typo while I was removing some unnecessary class properties.  It's a functional class / EF model in the code.